# How to call a function from react-navigation header?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am actually using react navigation https://reactnavigation.org/, I have a Component with a method:

```
class Sing extends Component {
   singASong = () => {
     console.log('hello i am singing');
   }
}
```

this component will be rendered with *react-navigation* and a custom *header*, the question is: how to call the method `singASong` from the custom header?:

```
const routeStackNavigation = {
  SingingMode: {
    screen: Sing,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: (
        <CustomNav onPressAction={() =>{
                 // how to call the method singASong from here ?
                }
              }
        />
      ),
    }),
  },
};
```

**UPDATE**

I set and test the value with this:

```
  this.props.navigation.setParams({'onPress': 'akumen' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.props.navigation.getParam('onPress')); // akumen
    }, 2000);
```

And i tests values with:

```
      onPress={() =>{
        console.log('NAVIGATION',navigation);
        console.log('ON PRESS',navigation.getParam('onPress'));
        console.log('PARAMS',navigation.state.params);
        return navigation.getParam('onPress');
        }
      }
```

but get undefined

[image: Undefined Values]

**FOR STACK NAVIGATION**

Below I share pic with my real world example, it was a stack navigation and I did not notice before, but param it just set under the right stack, so take this as motivation to explore:

[image: Stack NAvigation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigation params:

In componentDidMount

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({onPressAction: ()=>this.singASong()})
```

In navigationOptions

```
<CustomNav onPressAction={navigation.getParam("onPressAction") }/>
```

Comment: it does not work, i got `undefined`and i don't know why

Comment: That's because `CustomNamv` is renderend (and onPressAction is assingned) before the `componentDidMount` in the component is called. Change it to `onPressAction={() => navigation.getParam("onPressAction")()}`

Comment: I did it in the updated code @m-p with `() => { return navigation.getParam('onPress') }` it does not return func, so it useless execute undefined

Comment: Don't return the function. Just execute it. Do exactly as i wrote `{() => navigation.getParam("onPressAction")()}` and do not forget the last `()` after the the `getParam` call.

Comment: Solved: the problem was because is a stacked router, I did not see that when try to apply code example to real word app. thank you, I will update question with this extra data (no relevant for example but acknowledged)